# How Can I Use Comparators and Collections In Order To Sort A Text File In Different Ways? (Java)?

Tags: java

Any ideas? How Can I Use Comparators and Collections In Order To Sort A Text File In Different Ways? (Java)?

Answer (score 0):

you've almost got it right:

For comparing integers use the following:

```
Integer.compareTo(int1, int2);
```

For comparing strings use:

```
string1.compareTo(string2);
```

For boolean types use:

```
Boolean.compare(boolean1, boolean2);
```

So you Comparator class will be the following:

```
new Comparator< EmployeeFX >(){

            @Override
            public int compare(EmployeeFX o1, EmployeeFX o2) {
                return Integer.compare(o1.getId(), o2.getId());
            }
        };
```

Comment: Thanks! But how do I name that method so that the following line of code "outputData("Output in Salaried order.", list, EmployeeOrdering.EMPLOYEE_ID);"        will work?  When I try to name the method "new Comparator<EmployeeFX> EMPLOYEE_ID" ,  the program does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Comparator is basically used to create multiple sort sequence. you can sort your object using any attribute.

Just one example for your reference.

```
public int compare(EmployeeFX emp1, EmployeeFX emp2) {

    return (emp1.getId() < emp2.getId()) ? -1
            : (emp1.getId() > emp2.getId()) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks! But what would I name that comparator so i could refer to it in my driver class? (For example, using the line of code EmployeeOrdering.EMPLOYEE_ID). I'm also wondering how would I pass the ID Numbers to that comparator so it knows to sort by ID?

Answer (score 0):

What is your expected out put.

In this case u get the data sorted with salary wise(That is your last sort). All other previous sort become irrelevant.